Vault init script not found despite named volume in Docker Compose
Vault init script not found despite named volume in Docker Compose
Problem
When starting my Vault container using Docker Compose, I get the error:
/bin/sh: /vault/scripts/init-vault.sh: not found
/bin/sh: /vault/scripts/init-vault.sh: not found

This happens despite the script being present in the correct location and using a named volume.
Project Structure
vault-consul/
├── .env
├── docker-compose.yml
├── services/
    ├── consul/
    │   ├── config.hcl
    │   └── policies/
    │       ├── admin.hcl
    │       └── readonly.hcl
    └── vault/
        ├── config.hcl
        ├── policies/
        │   ├── admin.hcl
        │   └── readonly.hcl
        └── scripts/
            └── init-vault.sh

Docker Compose Configuration
services:
  consul-server:
    image: hashicorp/consul:latest
    container_name: consul-server
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - CONSUL_ALLOW_PRIVILEGED_PORTS=1
      - CONSUL_ACL_TOKEN=${CONSUL_ACL_TOKEN}
    command: >
      agent -server
        -bootstrap-expect=1
        -ui
        -client=0.0.0.0
        -node=consul-server
        -config-dir=/consul/config
    configs:
      - source: consul_config
        target: /consul/config/config.hcl
    volumes:
      - consul-data:/consul/data
    ports:
      - "${CONSUL_UI_PORT:-8500}:8500"
    networks:
      - hashicorp
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "consul", "members"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  vault:
    image: hashicorp/vault:latest
    container_name: vault
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - VAULT_ADDR=http://0.0.0.0:${VAULT_UI_PORT:-8200}
      - VAULT_API_ADDR=http://0.0.0.0:${VAULT_UI_PORT:-8200}
      - ENTRA_TENANT_ID=${ENTRA_TENANT_ID}
      - ENTRA_CLIENT_ID=${ENTRA_CLIENT_ID}
      - ENTRA_CLIENT_SECRET=${ENTRA_CLIENT_SECRET}
      - VAULT_REDIRECT_URIS=${VAULT_REDIRECT_URIS:-https://my-dns-address/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback}
      - ENTRA_ADMIN_GROUP_ID=${ENTRA_ADMIN_GROUP_ID}
      - ENTRA_READONLY_GROUP_ID=${ENTRA_READONLY_GROUP_ID}
      - CONSUL_ACL_TOKEN=${CONSUL_ACL_TOKEN}
    configs:
      - source: vault_config
        target: /vault/config/vault.hcl
      - source: vault_admin_policy
        target: /vault/policies/admin.hcl
      - source: vault_readonly_policy
        target: /vault/policies/readonly.hcl
    volumes:
      - vault-data:/vault/data
      - vault-logs:/vault/logs
      - vault-scripts:/vault/scripts
    ports:
      - "${VAULT_UI_PORT:-8200}:8200"
      - "${VAULT_API_PORT:-8201}:8201"
    depends_on:
      consul-server:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - hashicorp
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "vault", "status"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    entrypoint: sh -c
    command: "/vault/scripts/init-vault.sh && vault server -config=/vault/config/vault.hcl"

configs:
  consul_config:
    file: ./services/consul/config.hcl
  vault_config:
    file: ./services/vault/config.hcl
  vault_admin_policy:
    file: ./services/vault/policies/admin.hcl
  vault_readonly_policy:
    file: ./services/vault/policies/readonly.hcl

networks:
  hashicorp:
    name: hashicorp
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  consul-data:
    external: ${USE_EXTERNAL_VOLUMES:-false}
    name: ${CONSUL_DATA_VOLUME:-consul-data}
  vault-data:
    external: ${USE_EXTERNAL_VOLUMES:-false}
    name: ${VAULT_DATA_VOLUME:-vault-data}
  vault-logs:
    external: ${USE_EXTERNAL_VOLUMES:-false}
    name: ${VAULT_LOGS_VOLUME:-vault-logs}
  vault-scripts:
    external: ${USE_EXTERNAL_VOLUMES:-false}
    name: ${VAULT_SCRIPTS_VOLUME:-vault-scripts}

Configuration Files
services/consul/config.hcl
datacenter = "dc1"
data_dir = "/consul/data"
log_level = "INFO"
server = true
client_addr = "0.0.0.0"

telemetry {
  disable_hostname = true
  prometheus_retention_time = "24h"
}

acl {
  enabled = true
  default_policy = "deny"
  enable_token_persistence = true
  tokens {
    initial_management = "${CONSUL_ACL_TOKEN}"
  }
}

connect {
  enabled = true
}

ui_config {
  enabled = true
}

services/vault/config.hcl
ui = true

storage "consul" {
  address = "consul-server:8500"
  path    = "vault/"
  scheme  = "http"
  token   = "${CONSUL_ACL_TOKEN}"
}

service_registration "consul" {
  address = "http://vault:8200"
  token   = "${CONSUL_ACL_TOKEN}"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address     = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
}

telemetry {
  prometheus_retention_time = "24h"
  disable_hostname         = true
}

api_addr     = "http://0.0.0.0:8200"
cluster_addr = "http://0.0.0.0:8201"

disable_mlock = true

services/vault/scripts/init-vault.sh
#!/bin/bash
# init-vault.sh

# Function to load policies
load_policies() {
    local token=$1
    
    # Login with provided token
    vault login "$token"
    
    echo "Loading policies..."
    vault policy write admin /vault/policies/admin.hcl
    vault policy write readonly /vault/policies/readonly.hcl
}

vault server -config=/vault/config/vault.hcl

# Wait for dependencies
until curl -fs http://localhost:8500/v1/status/leader > /dev/null; do
    echo "Waiting for Consul to be ready..."
    sleep 2
done

until curl -fs http://localhost:8200/v1/sys/health > /dev/null; do
    echo "Waiting for Vault to start..."
    sleep 2
done

# Check if Vault is already initialized
if ! vault status > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Initializing Vault..."
    
    # Initialize Vault
    init_output=$(vault operator init \
        -key-shares=5 \
        -key-threshold=3 \
        -format=json)

    # Save initialization output securely
    echo "$init_output" | vault kv put secret/init-keys keys=-

    # Extract root token and unseal keys
    root_token=$(echo "$init_output" | jq -r '.root_token')
    unseal_key_1=$(echo "$init_output" | jq -r '.unseal_keys_b64[0]')
    unseal_key_2=$(echo "$init_output" | jq -r '.unseal_keys_b64[1]')
    unseal_key_3=$(echo "$init_output" | jq -r '.unseal_keys_b64[2]')

    # Unseal Vault
    vault operator unseal "$unseal_key_1"
    vault operator unseal "$unseal_key_2"
    vault operator unseal "$unseal_key_3"

    # Load policies
    load_policies "$root_token"

    # Enable OIDC auth
    vault auth enable oidc

    # Configure OIDC with Microsoft Entra ID
    vault write auth/oidc/config \
        oidc_discovery_url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/${ENTRA_TENANT_ID}/v2.0" \
        oidc_client_id="${ENTRA_CLIENT_ID}" \
        oidc_client_secret="${ENTRA_CLIENT_SECRET}" \
        default_role="readonly"

    # Create roles for different groups
    # Admin role
    vault write auth/oidc/role/admin \
        bound_audiences="${ENTRA_CLIENT_ID}" \
        allowed_redirect_uris="${VAULT_REDIRECT_URIS}" \
        user_claim="email" \
        groups_claim="groups" \
        bound_claims="groups=${ENTRA_ADMIN_GROUP_ID}" \
        policies="admin" \
        ttl=1h \
        max_ttl=24h

    # Readonly role
    vault write auth/oidc/role/readonly \
        bound_audiences="${ENTRA_CLIENT_ID}" \
        allowed_redirect_uris="${VAULT_REDIRECT_URIS}" \
        user_claim="email" \
        groups_claim="groups" \
        bound_claims="groups=${ENTRA_READONLY_GROUP_ID}" \
        policies="readonly" \
        ttl=1h \
        max_ttl=8h

    echo "Vault initialization complete. Please save the root token and unseal keys from secret/init-keys"
    
else
    echo "Vault is already initialized"
fi

# Enable audit logging
vault audit enable file file_path=/vault/logs/audit.log

echo "Vault setup completed successfully"

Environment

Docker version: 27.4.0, build bde2b89
Docker Compose version: v2.31.0-desktop.2
OS: Windows 11 Pro

What I've Tried

Verified the script exists in the correct location (services/vault/scripts/init-vault.sh)
Using a named volume for the scripts directory
Checked file permissions
Verified the volume is mounted using docker inspect

Question
Why isn't the init script found at runtime despite using a named volume? How can I ensure the script is available when the container starts?

The issue is that you are using a named volume for the /vault/scripts directory in your docker-compose.yml. Named volumes don't reference local files, which means the init-vault.sh script from your project directory is not being copied into the container.

To fix it, you should use a bind mount instead of a named volume for the /vault/scripts directory:
`volumes:

./services/vault/scripts:/vault/scripts`

This will make the init-vault.sh script available inside the container at runtime.

When you use a named volume like vault-scripts:/vault/scripts, Docker creates a persistent volume for you. I think this volume won't have any files unless they are explicitly written to it or pre-populated in some way.
In your case, you're trying to mount a script (init-vault.sh) from your local host (under ./services/vault/scripts), but using a named volume doesn't automatically include that file inside the container. That's why Vault cannot find your script . The proposed solution above should work, please let me know how it goes
